# Игнорирование Двойного клика по элементу списка CheckListBox без мигания галочкой

Tags: c#, winforms

Ниже приведен код *(c# winforms net4.0 vs2010)* для `CheckListBox1`, расположенного на форме1: флажок устанавливается только при одном клике на одном *(единовременно)* элементе списка.

При двойном клике на элементе списка с включенным флажком, флажок не должен выключаться - это работает в коде `"private void CheckListBox1_MouseDoubleClick"`, но не так как хотелось бы, т.е. если дважды щелкнуть по выделенному элементу списка, то флажок как бы "дергается" *(быстро выключается и снова включается)*, это заметно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как полностью отключить реакцию на двойной клик для элемента списка с уже включенным флажком, т.е. если дважды щелкнуть по уже выделенному элементу - ничего не должно происходить.

### Вот код:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckListBox1.Sorted = true;
    CheckListBox1.TopIndex = 0;
    CheckListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
    CheckListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
}

private void CheckListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < CheckListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
    {
        if (ix != e.Index)
        {
            CheckListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
        }
    }
}

private void CheckListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckListBox1.SetItemChecked(CheckListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
}

private void CheckListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CheckListBox1.SetItemChecked(CheckListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема мигания в том, что ты допускаешь 3 раза изменения Checked значения (например: поставить, снять, увидеть что она снята зря и поставить снова).

Вместо этого нужно просто не допускать снимания галочки при втором клике на протяжении некоторого времени.

```
    DateTime _lastClickTime = DateTime.Now;
    int _lastClickedObject = -1;
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        //анчек всех элементов окроме заселекченого
        for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
            if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);

        //логика игнорирования даблклика
        if (e.Index == _lastClickedObject &&
           (_lastClickTime.Ticks > DateTime.Now.Ticks - 2000000))
        {
            e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
        }

        //обновление значений для логики игнорирования даблклика
        _lastClickedObject = e.Index;
        _lastClickTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Потом подбираешь более удобное для тебя число вместо 2000000 что бы подобрать время которое можно считать за даблклик или уже считать за 2 отдельных клика

Comment: добавила в существующий код "checkedListBox1_ItemCheck". На строке "CheckListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);" ошибка. И флажки перестали включаться при выделении элемента одним кликом.

Comment: какая ошибка?  на какой строке? У меня нету такой строки)

Comment: Добавила в конец кода "checkedListBox1_ItemCheck". Ошибка "Необработанное исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException"".

Comment: Если оставить только Ваш код "checkedListBox1_ItemCheck", то не работает включение флажка по одному единовременно.

Comment: исправил, код рабочий на 100%

Comment: Не работает переключение флажка по одному (в списке должен быть с включенным флажком только выделенный элемент). Ваш код работает, но как добавить переключение по одному клику.

Comment: подправил.......

Comment: ошибка "Необработанное исключение типа "System.StackOverflowException"" в начале кода.

Comment: у меня на свежесозданном проэкте с этим кодом никаких ошибок. Независимо от того есть чекбоксы в контроле или нет.

Comment: Ошибка появляется при переключении по элементам списка.

Comment: У меня не появляется

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь! Возможно где-то в другом месте всего моего кода происходит влияние.

Comment: на этом сайте -- галочка и стрелочка вверх -- лучшая вариация "спасибо" :)

Comment: [SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime?view=netframework-4.7.2) - время дабл-клика, установленное в системе конкретного пользователя.